# Can I use selenium to click this element on the website?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I am trying to click an element for one website.

The source is:

```
<dd data-value="33" data-text="" data-target="brand">奥迪</dd>
```

It is supposed to be a dropdown button that clickable, but I've tried different methods:

- find_elements_by_css_selector
- find_elements_by_xpath that I just copied from google

But it turns out that the element the selenium found is not clickable. I am curious I can still click it.

The website is https://www.autohome.com.cn/beijing/ (you probably need to translate it into English).

[image: I want to click the Audi here].

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Furtherly, as I am going to click all car brands here for scraping, I hope the methods can be generalized to other cars such as Alfa Romeo listed in the figure.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong element to open it up.

```
<div class="option option-brand">
```

Just showed an example in Python.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.autohome.com.cn/beijing/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.option.option-brand"))).click()
name='奥迪'
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//dd[.='{}']".format(name)))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```